# Choice of visualisation for timestamp instances

Tags: information-graphics, data-visualisation

I have two lists of timestamps. Each of the lists look like this:

```
...
26/Nov/2023:21:19:57 +0000
26/Nov/2023:21:20:02 +0000
26/Nov/2023:21:20:23 +0000
26/Nov/2023:21:26:32 +0000
26/Nov/2023:21:46:17 +0000
26/Nov/2023:21:49:43 +0000
26/Nov/2023:21:50:01 +0000
26/Nov/2023:21:51:54 +0000
26/Nov/2023:21:52:08 +0000
...
```

Each timestamp represent one instance of a certain activity.

I would like to somehow visualise these two lists against each other. The goal is to show that the two lists alternate, mostly completing each other, but very rarely or never overlap (i.e. there should be at least a few seconds between any two points from different lists). Manual inspection indicates that this is the case, but it would be a lot easier to see with a good visualisation.

My first thought was to just plot two horisontal bars, with time on the X-axis, something like this:
[image: Basic plot with two horisontal lines]

There are, however, a few aspects that make this approach impractical.
For instance, both of the lists have about 5000 timestamps each, over a span of the seven-day period in question, and seconds matter (so a granularity of, say, 10 minutes is not detailed enough). So even if a second was only one pixel wide, it would still be a loooong and one-dimensional plot. Not very practical.

There is no requirement to have it all continuous, so you could for example split the week into seven independent days, and as such have 14 bars stacked on top of each other. It would still be a very long plot.

This shouldn't be treated as continuous activity but independent instances of activity. So even with four instances in ten seconds should still be treated as four points, not as a ten second interval. There can also be periods of hours with no timestamps from either list.

I am simply at a loss for how to visualise this in a clever way. Your input and ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: If you don't use all of the data available at one time most of your problems with this approach go away